# How to update and order by in joins in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

My first table is #temptbl(inserting data from select query)

[image]

2nd table is RWSupervisor table
 [image]

I want to update the table #temptbl in which Supervisory_date as closed_date and Supervisory_time as close_time(RWSupervisor table) and I want to apply order by Close_date and Close_time in RWSupervisor table.

I am using sql server 2005.How would be the query.
I have been trying somewhat like this-

```
WITH  #Temptbl AS
        (
        SELECT   *
        FROM   RWSupervisor
        ORDER BY Close_date,Close_time 
        ) UPDATE #Temptbl
    SET Supervisory_date = RWS.Close_date,
        Supervisory_time = RWS.Close_Time
       from #Temptbl su join RWOpen_Problems rwp
on su.Terminal_Id = rwp.Terminal_Id 
inner join RWSupervisor  RWS 
 ON su.Terminal_Id = RWS.Terminal_ID
 where
     ( su.Close_Date  = '' and ((RWS.Close_date  <= su.comments_date AND RWS.Close_date  >= (DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE())-1,0))) and (RWS.Close_time <= su.comments_Time and RWS.Close_time >=('23:59:00')) )
       )
OR
((RWS.Close_date  >= su.comments_date and RWS.Close_date <= su.Close_Date) and (RWS.Close_time >= su.comments_Time and RWS.Close_time <= su.Close_Time)) and rwp.Fault_Sid IN (1301,1302)
 and  su.Terminal_Id = 'P1DCDL06'
```

for e.g-in 3rd row supervisory_date and Supervisory_time should be '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000'    '10:34:26'

Comment: what dbms are u using?

Comment: Can you use `#` for the name of a CTE in SQL Server?

Comment: "sample data" in a reusable format would assist reaching an answer  (so that we can insert rows into a table)

Comment: sql server 2005 @ sagi

Comment: For e.g in 3rd row supervisory_date and Supervisory_time should be '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000' '10:34:26'

Comment: You don't want `ORDER BY` (which would imply you want _all_ rows, or at least a subset), you appear to want `MIN` (**one** row).  If you're updating "supervisory date/time", why not the "close" date/time in #temptbl as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's too difficult to figure out exactly what you're trying to do but I can take a decent guess.

It seems you have a view or query somewhere else in your system that fetches the RWSupervisor list. Up until you started updating it all the dates were displaying nicely in order so it seems like the `UPDATE` has messed up the order of the table.

The thing is, **tables have no order**. Often, but not always, they will output in the same order that new rows were inserted. That's why things seemed ok uptil now.

- Go to the query that is displaying the data in the wrong order and put `ORDER BY Close_date,Close_time` on.
- Put your update query back to a version that does the update.

It's hard to be more specific than that because there are a number of things in your example query that don't make sense and don't match your displayed data.

- A CTE is different to a #TempTbl .
  A CTE is what you're trying to use when you type `WITH` . The `#` , however denotes a temp table. If you want to create a temp table do it like

--

```
SELECT   *
INTO #Temptbl
FROM   RWSupervisor
```

- If you update the temp table as you're aiming to that won't affect the central data.
- Joining the temp Table to RWSupervisor only on Terminal_Id will return many times more rows than you're expecting because according to your screenshots that ID isn't unique in either table.

I'd advise getting away from the temp table if you can. If you need it for some reason then make sure it contains the primary key of the table you want to update (usually the first ID column). Use that for your join.

It also seems you're very new to SQL and you would have a much happier time if you did an [online tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) or two before updating production data.

Comment: @Adamantish.I am using temptable bcoz from select query I am inserting data into temp table.And except Terminal_Id,I dont have any other unique value  ,and so I need to use an update for the same..

Comment: @tbs Tables don't have an order. They are like a big bag of unsorted records. They often have indexes on them which help to sort them when you need them to be but if you `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` what you get back only **looks** like an orderly list because it would be hard to display otherwise. 
Considering you can't permanently order a table that's why you can't do it in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @tbs I still don't understand why you're using a temp table. You say it's because you are inserting into it with a SELECT query but you haven't included that in your code to show what the purpose is, why or whether you mean before the update or after.